# Cannot connect to Cygwin-based OpenSSH server with authorized_keys

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, openssh, sshd

I have a problem with setting-up SSHD service in Windows 7 running Cygwin.
I've followed [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29505_01/install.1111/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm) and it worked first time, but after reboot public keys stored in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` won't allow me to access this machine from external CLI. In addition password authorization also doesn't work, i've even try to reset password in cygwin using `passwd testinguser`.

These are steps i've made so far:

- Reinstall Cygwin SSHD service (I've also removed other Windows user accounts than testinguser)
- Re-run ssh-host-config again, as mentioned in tutorial
- reset testinguser password from Cygwin console
- set privileges to .authorized_keys & parent folder:

  `chmod 700 ~/.ssh &
  chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- disabled Windows Defender Firewall and other AV software (httpd works well)

below is the result of `ssh <host> -v` command:

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version WeOnlyDo 2.1.3
debug1: no match: WeOnlyDo 2.1.3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.1p1 Debian-4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 5d:9b:19:36:1c:67:1d:c9:ef:91:7c:1e:e8:3b:ba:12
debug1: Host '10.1.0.46' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/banasiak/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/banasiak/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: banasiak@pc-71-wroc
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/banasiak/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/banasiak/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Is there something else that I should check? SSHD service is running correctly, I can start&stop it without any errors.